# How to use a Pipe to filter into two lists in Ionic

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am having trouble with a todo list. I have an array of tasks, when a task is checked it has to show a title 'Finished tasks' and the task checked has to move to the bottom to finished tasks and have a line through it, if unchecked, it moves back to the top. To solution this I need to use Pipes, however, I am having a hell of a time and can't work it out as the tasks are always duplicated when I add the pipe, so obviously I am adding it wrong.
home.html

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor='let tarea of servicio.tareas | sort'><ion-item ><ion-checkbox color="dark" checked='false' (click)='checked(tarea)'></ion-checkbox>
 <div id="padding"><b>{{tarea.nombre}}</b></div>    
 </ion-item>    
 <ion-item-options side="end">    
 <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="editar(tarea.nombre, index)" >    
 <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>    
EDITAR    
 </button>    
 <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="eliminar(tarea)">    
 <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>    
BORRAR    
 </button>    
 </ion-item-options>    
 </ion-item-sliding>    
</ion-list>    
<ion-list>    
 <label \\\*ngIf='(servicio.tareas | filter).length > 0'>Tareas terminadas</label>    
</ion-list>
```

As you can see, I have the original sliding list with the pipe that sorts from important to non important, which works fine, then I have the finished tasks lavel which will appear when the length of the filter pipe is more than 1.

Here is the filterPipe:

```
  name: 'filter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(tarea1: Tareas[]) {
      return tarea1.filter(tarea2 => tarea2.finalizada);  
}
}
```

This should be the result, when a task is marked it shows the finished tasks and the finished result underneath, when unchecked, it goes back at the top.

[List with finished tasks showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaVXC.png)

This is the last thing I need to do and it is literally driving me mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're having trouble with mutating an object. By default, if you just switch the value of one of the attributes of one of the objects of your list, the sort pipe won't be executed again:

```js
const tarefas = [
  {
     id: 't1',
     finalizada: false,
  },
  {
     id: 't2',
     finalizada: true,
  }
];
```

In the code above, if you do `tarefas[0].finalizada = true` (or any other change in any attribute of a random `tarefas[index]`), the sort pipe won't run again.

What you can do is add a parameter to your pipe: `pure: false`. Then it will track changes to the objects inside your array:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'sort',
  pure: false
})
export class SortPipe...
```

As an alternative, you can change the reference of your `tarefas` object when you change an object attribute value:

```js
tarefa.finalizada = true;

servico.tarefas = [...service.tarefas];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works a charm, I can't believe how long it took me trying to get a solution myself :( Big thanks.

Comment: No worries. Just be warned that `pure: false` is performance-breaking. The second approach (changing the reference) is usually the recommended path.